# Google Cloud Print - Authorization Code exchange gives 401: unauthorized_client

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-print

I am trying to create a C# project that will walk a user through the registration of a new Google Cloud Print Printer. I've read every piece of documentation and troubleshooting I can find, and I'm still stumped.

Full details of Google's instructions can be [read here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/devguide).

The flow is supposed to go like this:

1. Printer makes an unauthenticated request to /register
2. Printer directs user to an invite URL
3. User logs in and claims printer
4. Printer polls a Url until user claims
5. Once claimed, printer gets an Auth Code
6. Printer exchanges Auth code for Access/Refresh tokens

I'm having trouble with step 6, as it always returns a 401: unauthorized_client error.

As I understand it from the documentation, at step 1, Google is creating a "Robot" (or Service) account for the printer, and the user is only associating themselves with this account as the owner. The printer is supposed to have its own access token to utilize the cloud print API and receive XMPP messages (jobs, etc.).

I have a theoretical work-around by having the user explicitly allow my project access to the /cloudprint and /googletalk APIs, then using the access and refresh tokens from the user's login to control the printer, but I'm afraid the robot account's JabberId will be inaccessible, as I have never exchanged the Auth code successfully.

I've been mostly using https://apigee.com/console/others to simulate the various http posts to Google, so I don't really have any code to show at the moment. Here is the POST for Step 6 being sent (with my client IDs hidden):

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Length: 250
X-Target-URI: https://accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Keep-Alive

client_id=xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&
redirect_uri=oob&
client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=4/ql0tDrttiY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Please note that this exact same request works perfectly when I get an auth code for a specific user that grants access to the APIs. I can also retrieve fresh access tokens utilizing the refresh token, though that API isn't quite correctly documented either; I need to replace "code" with "refresh_token", but the error message it gave was at least useful.

One other piece of information is that in Google Developer's Console, my Client ID is for a "native application", which wasn't specified anywhere in the documentation but seems to be heavily implied by the default (and unchangeable) Redirect Uris. I have tried using a Client Id for a Web Application, and I get the same result.

Thank you in advance for any clues or help you can give me.

Comment: I have no idea if this will help. I didn't even know this was possible. This link shows how googles Oauth flow works.  http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/  Love to know if you get this working.  Its an interesting idea.

Comment: I have gotten that process to work, but it doesn't seem to work for my printer's robot account. It seems like Google created a more streamlined version of that OAuth process specifically for cloud printers that doesn't require the user to grant any special permissions at all... just sign in and claim the printer. I've read several things that state that Step 1 of my process includes API permissions for /cloudprint and /googletalk for the robot account to be used by the project specified by the Client ID you use in the request for the Auth code, but I don't know of a way to very that.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think I've discovered what the issue is.

During Step 4 (when I retrieve the Authorization Code), Google takes whatever value you give it for the OAuth_client_id parameter, without checking to see that it's actually a valid Client ID. I had an extra space in the URL parameter, which I didn't notice and no error was given. The Auth Code returned must have incorporated this space as part of the Client ID it was expecting in Step 6, which I was not (of course) providing. I only discovered my mistake by recreating everything from scratch.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Here are the POSTs I was making, for anyone looking for examples:

[POST to /Register that creates a new printer](https://apigee.com/console/others?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcloudprint%2Fregister%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22headers_name_0%22%3A%22Content-Type%22%2C%22headers_value_0%22%3A%22application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%22%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22undefined%22%3A%22%5Cu0001%5Cu0001%22%2C%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%2C%22bodyText%22%3A%22name%3Dpost%20test%20printer%26default_display_name%3Ddefault%20name%26proxy%3Dproxy1%26uuid%3D0%26manufacturer%3DDefault%26model%3D1%26gcp_version%3D2.0%26setup_url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-print%2F%26support_url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-print%2F%26update_url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-print%2F%26firmware%3D1%26semantic_state%3D%7B%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%221.0%5C%22%7D%26use_cdd%3Dtrue%26capabilities%3D%7B%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%221.0%5C%22%7D%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22post%22%7D)

Follow returned complete_invite_url link and claim the printer with your Google account.

[POST to Polling URL](https://apigee.com/console/others?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcloudprint%2Fgetauthcode%3Fprinterid%3D%7Bprinter%20ID%20from%20Step%201%7D%26oauth_client_id%3D%7BJUST%20your%20client%20ID%20from%20the%20Dev%20Console%7D%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22parameters_name_0%22%3A%22printerid%22%2C%22parameters_value_0%22%3A%22%7Bprinter%20ID%20from%20Step%201%7D%22%2C%22parameters_name_1%22%3A%22oauth_client_id%22%2C%22parameters_value_1%22%3A%22%7BJUST%20your%20client%20ID%20from%20the%20Dev%20Console%7D%22%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22headers_name_0%22%3A%22X-CloudPrint-Proxy%22%2C%22headers_value_0%22%3A%22Google%22%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22post%22%7D)

[POST to OAuth2 API](https://apigee.com/console/others?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Ftoken%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22headers_name_0%22%3A%22Content-Type%22%2C%22headers_value_0%22%3A%22application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%22%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22undefined%22%3A%22%5Cu0001%5Cu0001%22%2C%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%2C%22bodyText%22%3A%22client_id%3D%7Byour%20client%20id%7D%26redirect_uri%3Doob%26client_secret%3D%7Byour%20client%20secret%7D%26grant_type%3Dauthorization_code%26code%3D%7BAuth%20Code%20from%20previous%20step%7D%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22post%22%7D)

[POST to /delete to clean up](https://apigee.com/console/others?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcloudprint%2Fdelete%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22headers_name_0%22%3A%22Content-Type%22%2C%22headers_value_0%22%3A%22application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%22%2C%22headers_name_1%22%3A%22Authorization%22%2C%22headers_value_1%22%3A%22OAuth%20%7BAccess%20Token%20from%20previous%20step%7D%22%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22undefined%22%3A%22%5Cu0001%5Cu0001%22%2C%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%2C%22bodyText%22%3A%22printerid%3D%7Bprinter%20id%20returned%20in%20Step%201%7D%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22post%22%7D)

Good luck to everyone using this API!